# Perform transform on Kendo UI chart binding in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm using a Kendo UI Chart together with Angular, binding to my series in HTML:

```
<div kendo-chart
    k-data-source="result.Details"
    k-series="[
             { xField: 'myX.value', yField: 'myY.value' },
             { xField: 'myX.value', yField: 'myOtherY.value' }]"
    k-series-defaults="{ type: 'scatterLine' }"></div>
```

Why the `myX.value`, and not just `myX`? Because this is published to both a .NET client and a Web client. The .NET client receives a class that has both a `Value` property and a `Unit` property (i.e. 3 meters, or 20 kilograms).

I was wondering if I can't just perform a function on my xField and yField values? Something like:

```
{xField: 'Transform(myX.value)', yField: 'Transform(myY.value)' }
```

**Why?**

This is a trivial example where the transform isn't necessary (because I can bind to `myX.value`). But due to how I serialize to JSON for .NET, I need to serialize differently for Web. I would like to serialize the same way for both, but that would mean my Web/js code would receive `myX` as "20 kg". I would then need to parse out the 20.

Comment: Could you make the transform function a responsibility of the `result.Details` model and not the responsibility of your serialization?

Comment: @Brett hm, possibly. Now I'm just receiving the object as sent and parsed via SignalR. I guess I could add some functions to the object or transform before binding it. I'll give it a go.

Comment: That would be my recommendation. You shouldn't need to change your serialization based on the platform. Make the platform responsible for transforming the serialized data for its own needs.

Comment: If you want, you can post this as an answer. I essentially did change my server-side code because I'd have to parse too many properties from too many objects. But your answer is right, my specific situation is just different.